# Вставка формы XAML в приложение на C#

Tags: c#, xaml

Вопрос, скорее всего, весьма наивный, но никак не могу найти подходящего ответа.
Есть основная программа, написанная на C#. Из нее надо создать новое окно.

Вставил элемент XML. Дописал его вручную.

```
<UserControl x:Class="Nevatec_Demo.Ship.UserControl" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Nevatec_Demo"
mc:Ignorable="d" d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="450">
    <Canvas>
        <Path Name="_ShipProfile" Canvas.Top="15" Canvas.Left="-16" Fill=" Red"
        Stroke="Gainsboro" StrokeThickness="2" Data="M 90, 30 L 90, 90 ... Z" DataContext="{Binding}"></Path>
        <Path Name="_Arrow" Canvas.Top="0" Canvas.Left="0" StrokeThickness="5"
        Stroke="Green" Data="M 200,30 L120,30 ..." Height="43" Width="450"></Path>
    </Canvas>
</UserControl>
```

Вопрос - как его подключить к основной программе?

Доп.: При переходе к коду создается ship.xaml.cs:

```
// ...

namespace Nevatec_Demo
{
    public partial class Ship : Form1
    {
        public Ship()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

Вот этот `InitilizeComponent` - "недоступен из-за его уровня защиты". Хотелось бы, чтобы это окно открывалось как дочернее и управление элементами `_ShipProfile` и `_Arrow` было из основного кода.

Comment: XML исправьте на xaml в одном месте. :) Основная программа - это что(WPF или WinForms)? Работаете через Visual Studio? В VS есть небольшой глюк при работе с xaml-ем на WinForms.

Comment: Не-не, вы делаете что-то не то. Проще всего просто переделать своё приложение на WPF. Или если очень не хочется, сделайте отдельную WPF-assembly, добавьте её как reference, и вставляйте через [element host](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.integration.elementhost.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

В системе все сделано логично. Вы немного запутались, но по сути не понятно что же вы хотите получить. Вы открываете свой контрол, но где он находится? если у вас есть форма WPF, то в ней все просто, если есть WindowsForms форма, то там тоже есть WPF host. Но сам контрол просто так не отобразить. А доступ можно получить, только из вопроса не понятна ваша структура программы.

Comment: Спасибо semenvx27!
На самом деле мне действительно надо переформулировать вопрос.
Задача стоит следующим образом:
Есть основная программа, которую хотелось бы сделать в основном окне.
Из основного окна должно вызываться несколько окон, которые должны показывать текстовые данные и некоторую графику, изменяющуюся в следствие изменений данных из основного потока.
XAML интересен тем, что я там увидел возможность простого изменения фигур.
Может быть, есть и другой способ заставить все корректно работать.
Работаю из VS2010. Создается Windows Form. Вопрос

Comment: Вопрос стоит как сделать?